# How to have wget entire set of text data?

Tags: wget

I have Ubuntu 18.4.  I recently found out about wget and tried it on a remote file of my data that I've been trying to get onto my PC for months with no luck.

I ran wget and it got the "front page" that sets up the display format for displaying the text I wrote over many years on that remote news site. But, it did not go any further.  I've looked at the code the site uses to display all of this text data and it is a combination of html and java.  I am not a programmer and have little understanding of all of their code which is extremely long. This site has not been a bit helpful to get all these old comments and text of mine.

I want to get my text data and be able to reformat it for a book I'd like to write.

Is there some way to have wget grab all of my data?  The site sometimes has a communication fault and drops the connection with an error message of "error-connection-retry" which may get reconnect and be OK or may get reconnected but start mixing different years of data for display, or may just freeze and not continue and I have had to start over from the top.

I've copied the sites code onto a WordPad doc, but it is a lot of pages long.  If it would help, I can copy the display of several pages of my text data as displayed to show what the site has set up for display that may or may not need to be dealt with if wget can actually deal with this.

Thanks,
Pat

Comment: wget will download the page you are requesting. Once you have the page downloaded you will need other means to parse your text. There could be many ways to do it depending on its format. 
I suspect it is not just raw text. What you are looking for is called web scraping. If you are nat familiar with HTML and scripting languages, you should look for a service that can help with it. Probably there will be some browsers extensions that can do what you need.

Comment: You may be interested in [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) as well.

Comment: " Probably there will be some browsers extensions that can do what you need."   Can you name any of them for me for Firefox or CHROME?

Comment: Firefox add on 'save as pdf'   . also pdftotext for terminal conversion. pdfgrep for searching.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use lynx as described in [this answer to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255538/70847).

You may have to install lynx and you will have to enable the [Universe repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#line-12):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install lynx
```

and then run it with the dump option like this:

```
lynx -dump https://example.com
```

To save this text to a file, you can pipe the output to `tee` like this:

```
lynx -dump https://example.com | tee filename.txt
```

This should dump the entire text of the page. Although there may be some unrelated text, the text you desire should be included without all the fancy code.

---

Another option would be to:

- go to the web page in your web browser
- double click on any word in the text portion of the page
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all of the text
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy the text
- then paste the text into a text editor or a word document or wherever

One thing to make this option more easy would be to view the Google webcache "text only" version of the page.

From there, you can then use the method of copy and paste as described above.

To search for the Google webcache version of the page (if one exists) use the following URL syntax:

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:URL&strip=1&vwsrc=0
```

and replace "URL" with the actual URL of the page.

For example, to view the text only version of the **example.com** page, you would use the following URL:

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://example.com&strip=1&vwsrc=0
```

Comment: Let me know if these methods don't works as javascript sometimes interferes with these methods. However, the simple "copy and paste" method should work from your web browser if nothing else works.

Comment: Also, if the Google webcache URL returns "page not found" that means the cached version of the page doesn't exist. I just thought it might be easier to copy and paste a "text only" version of the page.